# Firebase UI delay in populating View?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am using firebase UI List adapter but whenever the activity is opened it takes quiet a lot of time like 5-8 seconds before it shows something in list . There is no issue with my network i am not getting where exactly problem is . My code is like this .

I am fetching data inside the **fragment** like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coming, container, false);

        final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        comingList =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewComing);

        FirebaseListAdapter<userData> firebaseListAdapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<userData>(
                getActivity(),
                userData.class,
                R.layout.item_list,
                mDatabase.child("coming"))
        {

            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, userData model, int position) {

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewList);
                TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewList);
                textView.setText(model.getName());
                Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(model.getImageURI())).into(imageView);

            }
        };

        comingList.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);

        return view;

    }
```

So basically i need solution for

1. Fetch data fast
2. How to implement add progress indicator in fragment for firebaseUI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by enabling offline cache in Firebase

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```